# Can't understand how 'return' works

Tags: c++, return

I'm studying the following code, which aims to find out solutions of x and y in an extended Euclid algorithm:

```
long gcd(long a, long b, long &x, long &y) {
    long d; // place to hold final gcd
    // in case b = 0, we have d=|a|, x=1 or -1, y arbitrary (say, 0)
    if (b==0) {
        if (a<0) {
            d = -a;
            x = -1;
            y = 0;
        } else {
            d = a;
            x = 1;
            y = 0;
        }
        return d;
    }
    // if b is negative, here is a workaround
    if (b<0) {
        d = gcd(a,-b,x,y);
        y = -y;
        return d;
    }
    // if a is negative, here is a workaround
    if (a<0) {
        d = gcd(-a,b,x,y);
        x = -x;
        return d;
    }
    // set up recursion
    long aa = b;
    long bb = a%b;
    long qq = a/b;
    long xx,yy;
    d = gcd(aa,bb,xx,yy);
    x = yy +1;
    y = xx - qq*yy;
    return d;
}
```

What I really don't understand is how 'return d' works.
Given two input numbers (a, b), I'm trying to follow all the behaviours looking at the debug session (using Apple Xcode).

Once b == 0, it goes here:

```
if (b==0) {
    if (a<0) {
        d = -a;
        x = -1;
        y = 0;
    } else {
        d = a;
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
    }
    return d;
}
```

and from this 'return d' it jumps to the last 'return d' at the end of the code.
Once there, it starts looping this last chunk of code:

```
    d = gcd(aa,bb,xx,yy);
    x = yy +1;
    y = xx - qq*yy;
    return d;
}
```

until all the solutions are found.

My question are:

1) why from the first 'return d' it jumps straight to the last 'return d'? 
2) how can be possible that from there it remains in the last four lines until the end instead of calling the function

```
d = gcd(aa,bb,xx,yy);
```

as done before?

Here I post also the main:

```
int main() {

    long a,b,x,y;

    cout << "Insert first ---> ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Insert second ---> ";
    cin >> b;




    cout << "The gcd of " << a << " and " << b << " is "
         << gcd(a,b,x,y)<<endl;

    cout << "x is " << x << " and y is " << y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `return d` does not jump anywhere but where the function was called from. It is a standard statement that immediately ends function's execution, destroys all the locals in last-first order and feeds the provided value to the callee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you step from `return d;`, you should end up at the end of the function, which is its closing brace.

   If you start putting closing braces on a line of their own, you'll be able to tell the difference between "the last statement" and "the end of the function".
2. Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions – each call returns to the point immediately after that call; in your case every call to `gcd(aa,bb,xx,yy);` will return to the line `x = yy +1;` and that's why you think those lines are being looped.

   (If you open the debugger's callstack window, you will see that it grows as functions are called and shrinks as you return from them, and your "loop" is the return to the same point in several *separate* function invocations.)

Answer (score 0):

Are there sequential calls to it in main? That's the only reason I can fathom that it would do that. For example:

```
long g1 = gcd(3, 0, x, y);
long g2 = gcd(3, 2, x, y);
```

This would, in theory, cause that first if statement to be true and evaluate as such, but then the second call to gcd would bypass all of the if statements and go straight to the bottom.

Edit: I suppose I don't really understand the question and shouldn't have attempted to answer. However, what I do know is that, from the code provided, there are four possible paths that gcd can take when called:

1. `b==0` This returns the absolute value of `a` and sets `x = -1` if `a` was negative (or 1 if not, obviously).
2. `b<0` This returns the result of a call to gcd with the absolute value of `b` and negates the `y` variable that was passed by reference.
3. `a<0` Same as path 2, but with `a` and `x` instead of `b` and `y`.
4. None of the above are true, and weird stuff happens (I haven't had to use this algorithm (I know, I'm a simpleton)).

This probably doesn't answer your question very well, but it's how I always break these types of problems down for analysis and troubleshooting, so I hope it was of some use at least for introducing you to the step-by-step troubleshooting method if you haven't been using it already.

Comment: I've added the main code, please have a look if you think the answer is hidden there! Thanks